# Veins delay does not change with beacon frequency or number of nodes

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm trying to simulate an imergancy breaking application using veins and analyze its performance. Research papers on 802.11p shows that as beacon frequency and number of vehicles increase delay should increase considerably due to mac layer delay of the protocol ( for 50 vehicles at 8Hz  - about 300ms average delay).

But when simulating application with veins delay values does not show much different ( it ranges  from 1ms-4ms).I've checked the Mac layer functionality and it appears that the channel is idle most of the time. So when a packet reaches Mac layer the channel has already been idle for more than the DIFS so packet gets sent quickly. I tried increasing packet size and reducing bitrate. It increase the previous delay by a certain amount. But drastic increase of delay due to backoff process cannot be seen. 
 Do you know why this happens ???

Comment: How many vehicles (nodes) do you have in your scenario and how does it look like? How many other vehicles are typically located in a small range like 100m around a transmitting vehicle and are they transmitting at the same time as well? Please provide more details about your simulation.

Comment: I've used 50 nodes that has a gap of about 12m between them and travels at 100 kmph (28 ms^-1 ) A simple path loss module is used with alpha = 2 and Tx power 29mW with a range of about 510m. So about 8 vehicles are within 100m. In Veins a random offset is added to the first beacon (offset is less than 0.005s) So theirs a slight difference in the time each node beacons. Transmitted packets are 500bytes in size. I've also tried increasing no of nodes ( about 250 nodes in a single lane with the same gap as before, 4 parallel lanes with 50 nodes )

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you should only see this effect when the channel is actually approaching the capacity (i.e., most of the time, the channel is busy). I believe the research you mentioned also does that (but I'm not an expert in that field); I'd suggest increasing the load further (or reducing the bandwidth further) to see whether you can reproduce the effect. 11p has seen a lot of changes over the years, it might be that veins' is more recent or older than the version covered by the papers you mention.

Comment: How can I change the Bandwidth ??? Is it ok to change bandwidth since for 802.11p channel BW is specified as 10MHZ ???

Comment: I think what @RensvanderHeijden ment is to reduce the bit rate. The bandwidth is fixed at 10MHz for 802.11p as you mentioned already.

You mentioned "research papers on 802.11p", can you specify them by giving some references?

Comment: S. Eichler, "Performance evaluation of the IEEE
802.11p WAVE communication standard", Proceedings
of the Vehicular Technology Conference, Hameed Mir, Z. and Filali, F. (2014) „LTE and
IEEE 802.11p for vehicular networking: A performance
evaluation‟, EURASIP Journal on Wireless
Communications and Networking .  These papers shows higher delays. But we recently found this one, Effects of Transmission Queue Size, Buffer andScheduling Mechanisms on the IEEE 802.11p Beaconing
Performance, Luuk Hendriks, University of Twente shows lower delays.

Answer (score 0):

As you use 802.11p the default data rate on the control channel is 6Mbits (source: ETSI EN 302 663)

750Mbyte/s = 750.000bytes/s

Your beacons contain 500bytes. So the transmission of a beacon takes about 0.0007 seconds. As you have about 50 cars in your multi lane scenario and for example they are sending beacons with a 10 hertz frequency, it takes about 0.35s from 1 second to transmit your 500 beacons.

In my opinion, this are to less cars to create your mentioned effect, because the channel is idling for about 60% of the time.